# matplotlib 1.3.1 doesn't work with Python quantities package

Tags: python, matplotlib

After updating to matplotlib 1.3.1 it stopped working with the quantities package. For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import quantities as pq
import numpy as np
t = np.arange(0,10,0.1) * pq.sec
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)**2 * pq.m
plt.plot(t,x)
```

Brings a long, ugly exception log ending with "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". It seems to be a problem with the get_converter() method of matplotlib.units and arrays with quantities.

The way I found around the problem is:

```
plt.plot(t.magnitude,x.magnitude);
```

Which works well, but I have quite some scripts I would prefer not to change. Are there any other way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a nasty exception. Unfortunately, I can't think of any really good solutions short of modifying either the Quantities or Matplotlib source code. I would post this as a bug to [Matplotlib issues](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues). I suggest posting it to Matplotlib instead of Quantities because this problem didn't seem to happen with Matplotlib v1.3.0, but it is possible that this is easier to fix on the Quantities side.

So I think you're three options are

1. Do what you suggested, changing `x` to `x.magnitude`.
2. Write your own plot wrapper, that does the `x.magnitude`, as well as possibly putting labels on the axes that use the units of `x`, doing any conversion of the units (as Matplotlib was trying to do), or anything else you want to do with the units.
3. Downgrade your Matplotlib install to version 1.3.0.

Comment: Just for documentation. This issue seems to be the matplotlib pull request #2591: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2591

Comment: And it has been fixed in matplotlib 1.4.0